# How would you pass an C# object via com?

Tags: c#, c++, com

How would one pass a C# object via com? For example, say I have the following in a c# dll which is registered in the GAC and registry:

```
 public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

public int Add(NumberObject obj)
    {
        return obj.firstNumber + obj.SecondNumber;
    }
```

How is it possible to make the NumberObject comvisible so that the client, who is going to use this, can set its values? A c++ example would be great, is it even possible? Or are only native types like int, string etc passable by COM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a good [tutorial](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/building-com-objects-in-c/).

Comment: THanks, I couldn't find this by googling, maybe I was looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: FYI, my google search: http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+make+object+COM+visible